# Change IDLE tab width/ indent width Python

Tags: python, formatting, whitespace, python-idle

Just a minute ago I opened IDLE to start a new Python file. After I had written a function header, I pressed tab (from column 0) and it only indented two spaces rather than four. This hasn't happened to me before. How can I change/ reset the tab width to four spaces?

Comment: According to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/66/146609, number of columns that consist tab is environment specific.

Answer (score 1):

In the IDLE Preferences, under "Fonts/Tabs" there should be an "Indentation Width" preference, where you can change the tab width to four spaces.

Comment: Where are the IDLE Preferences or Preference tab?

Comment: Which Operating System are you using?

Comment: Options on the main menu had Configure Idle which opens the Idle Preferences dialog which should open to the Fonts/Tabs tab.  Indent is on the right.

Comment: If Idle does not indent exactly the expected 4 spaces, then you probably omitted something, line ':' or closing quote.